# Objectify Java Reference

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

```
@Entity
public class Category {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    @Load
    private List<Ref<Subcategory>> subcategories = new ArrayList<Ref<Subcategory>>();
    @Load
    private Ref<Image> image;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public List<Subcategory> getSubcategories() {
        List<Subcategory> scs = new ArrayList<Subcategory>();
        for (Ref<Subcategory> sc : this.subcategories) {
            scs.add(sc.get());
        }
        return scs;
    }

    public void setSubcategory(Subcategory subcategory) {
        this.subcategories.add(Ref.create(subcategory));
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        if(image != null) {
            return image.get();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void setImage(Image image) {
        this.image = Ref.create(image);
    }
}

@Entity
public class Subcategory {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class CategoryDTO {

    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;
    private String description;

    private List<Subcategory> subcategories = new ArrayList<Subcategory>();
    private Long imageId;

    public CategoryDTO() {
    }

    public CategoryDTO(Category category) {
        this.id = category.getId();
        this.name = category.getName();
        this.description = category.getDescription();
        this.subcategories = category.getSubcategories();

        if (category.getImage() != null) {
            this.imageId = category.getImage().getId();
        }
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public List<Subcategory> getSubcategories() {
        return subcategories;
    }

    public void setSubcategories(List<Subcategory> subcategories) {
        this.subcategories = subcategories;
    }

    public Long getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }

    public void setImageId(Long imageId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

}
```

CategoryDAO

```
public class CategoryDAO {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CategoryService.class.getName());

    public static QueryResultIterator<Category> getCategories() {
        QueryResultIterator<Category> categories = ofy().load().type(Category.class).iterator();
        return categories;
    }
}

public class SubcategoryDAO {

    public static Subcategory createSubcategory(Long categoryId, Subcategory data) {
        // save sub category
        Subcategory subcategory = new Subcategory();
        if (data.getName() != null) {
            subcategory.setName(data.getName());
        }
        if (data.getDescription() != null) {
            subcategory.setDescription(data.getDescription());
        }
        ofy().save().entity(subcategory).now();

        Category category =
            ofy().load().type(Category.class).id(categoryId).get();
        category.setSubcategory(subcategory);
        ofy().save().entity(category).now();

        return subcategory;
    }
}
```

CategoryService

```
@Path("/categories")
public class CategoryService {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getCategories() {
        try {
            List<CategoryDTO> categories = new ArrayList<CategoryDTO>();
            QueryResultIterator<Category> cats = CategoryDAO.getCategories();
            while (cats.hasNext()) {
                categories.add(new CategoryDTO(cats.next()));
            }
            Map<String, List<CategoryDTO>> map = new HashMap<String, List<CategoryDTO>>();
            map.put("categories", categories);
            return Helper.prepareResponse(map);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LogService.getLogger().severe(e.getMessage());
            throw new WebApplicationException(500);
        }
    }
}
```

Problem:-

When i hit getCategories service, it is showing unexpected behaviour.Instead of showing all the subcategories, it is showing random no of different subcategories every time.

For example say, 
first i save a category "c"
then i save subcategories "sa", "sb" and "sc"

On hitting getCategry service,

Expected Behaviour -

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "categories" : [{ 
        "name":a, 
        "subcategories": [
            {
                "name":"sa"
            }, 
            {
                "name":"sb"
            }, 
            {
                "name":"sc"
            } 
        ]
    }]
}
```

Outputs i get is something like this -

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "categories" : [{ 
        "name":a, 
        "subcategories": [
            {
                "name":"sa"
            }, 
            {
                "name":"sc"
            } 
        ]
    }]
}
```

or

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "categories" : [{ 
        "name":a, 
        "subcategories": [{
            "name":"sb"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To summarize this question, you're performing a query (give list of all categories) and getting back inconsistent results.

This is the system working as advertised. Read this:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency

Eventual consistency is something that you learn to live with and work around when you need it. There is no way to force a query to be strongly consistent without changing the structure of your data - say, put it under a single entity group - but that has repercussions as well. There is no free lunch if you want a globally replicated, infinitely-scalable database.

In addition to eventual consistency, the datastore has no defined ordering behavior if you do not specify a sort order in your query. So that might add to your confusion.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to the wonderful world of eventual consistency. When I encountered something like this, using ObjectifyService.begin() instead of ObjectifyService.ofy() resolved it. Unlike ofy(), begin() gets you fresh data every time.

Comment: I used ObjectifyService.factory().begin() instead of ObjectifyService.ofy() and it worked.Thanks you saved my day.Too bad i can't upvote because i don't have enough points.

Comment: This is absolutely, 100% the wrong answer. If it makes a difference, it's because you did not have the `ObjectifyFilter` installed. Taking this approach will produce some very strange bugs down the road, potentially including corrupted cache values and memory leaks. Read the javadocs for begin() to understand what you are doing.

Comment: I should add - that if it made a difference, it's probably because you waited long enough for the index to replicate (and thus the data became consistent). Your code change had no (positive) effect. If you're using a recent version of Objectify, it won't let you run without the filter installed.